# how to get the data before loading the page in angularjs providers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a requirement like to get the data before loading the page by using angular js providers ,am not implement it please anybody help me.

This is my code please go through it

```
hiregridApp.provider('organizationService', function() {
  return {
    getOrganization: ['$http', '$location',
      function($http, $location) {
        $http({
          method: 'GET',
          url: http: //dev.api.hiregrid.io/api/customer/token/hiregrid',
        }).success(function(data) {
          $log.log(data);
        }).error(function(error, status) {
          $routeParams.code = status;
          $location.path('/error/' + $routeParams.code);
        });
      }
    ]
  }, this.$get: ['$http', '$location',
    function($http, $location) {
      var obj = '';
      alert("hai");
      obj.getOrganization = function() {
        $http({
          method: 'GET',
          url: 'http://dev.api.hiregrid.io/csbuilder- api/api/csbuilder/hiregrid',
        }).success(function(data) {
          $log.log(data);
        }).error(function(error, status) {
          $routeParams.code = status;
          $location.path('/error/' + $routeParams.code);
        });
        return obj;
      }
    }
  ];
});
hiregridApp.config(function(organizationServiceProvider) {
  console.log(organizationServiceProvider);
  organizationServiceProvider.getOrganization("http://dev.api.hiregrid.io");
});
```

Comment: this feature is already provided by the `resolve` parameter in `ngRoute` or the 3rd party router `ui-router`.  Trying to solve it by hand will be very difficult without a deep understanding of asynchronous methods.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load data before page loaded, use `resolve` inside your router. For that you don't need providers.
About `resolve` you can read here [angular router](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider)

Answer (score 0):

You could resolve  your data in routing so when ever you navigate to a page it will resolve your data and then navigate. 
Note if server take long time to response so it will not navigate u till it has resolved your promise.

You can use your provider in config where you have your router configuration.

```
angular.module ('app',[]).config (function(yourProvider){})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   var config = { headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8;'}};
   App.provider('organizationService', ['$http',
    function($http) {
         return {
            getOrganization: function (){
                $http.get("http: //dev.api.hiregrid.io/api/customer/token/hiregrid",config)
                .success(function(data) {
      $log.log(data);
    }).error(function(error, status) {
      $routeParams.code = status;
      $location.path('/error/' + $routeParams.code);
    });
            }
         }
    }
]);
```

Comment: App.controller('JobPositionCtrl', function ($rootScope, $scope, organizationService) {}